# Call function inside trigger in PL/SQL

Tags: function, plsql, triggers

So I have a function that given a user id calculates his bmi (body mass index) based on his last weight measuring (I have a table that records all measurings), and I want to code a trigger that everytime a user inserts his weight, the triggers checks if the user bmi is below a limit. The function is ok, but i can't get the trigger to work here's what I have:

```
1  CREATE OR REPLACE
2  TRIGGER BMITG
3  AFTER INSERT ON WEIGHTS
4  BEGIN
5     IF BMI(USRID)>25
6     THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'Please control your weight.');
7     END IF;
8  END;
```

But I get the errors:
Error(6,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(6,10): PLS-00201: identifier 'IDENT' must be declared

I think te problem is that the db doesn't know that USRID is the user id of the INSERT that activates the trigger. How can I solve this problem?
BTW the table WEIGHTS has a user id (number), a date and a weight (number).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:new.id` instead of `USRID` and add `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: Thanks, the trigger now compiles but I get a 
"ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
when inserting on the table

Comment: @DanielNovais - Inside trigger you cannot `select` from the table on which your trigger is created.  Use `:new.column_name` to read data from column `column_name` of inserting row.